# C#: Read fast from a file that is being used by another process

Tags: python, c#

I have a python script that reads from a logfile and outputs certain data from it. The way it reads from it is

```
try:
    with open(os.path.expandvars('Path/To/My/Log.txt', 'r') as f:
        logContent = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Now I wanted to recreate that python script in C#. The main problem is, that the log file makes about 30.000 Lines in 30 minutes. While the program that handles that log isn't being executed, I can easily open the file and read from it, because it's not being used by that program. But when that program runs, I need to read from the file with a filestream, and so the reading of 30.000 lines takes ages:

```
private string GetLog(string path)
    {
        string log = "";

        FileStream reader = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader logFileReader = new StreamReader(reader);

        while (!logFileReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            log += logFileReader.ReadLine();
            // Your code here
        }

        // Clean up
        logFileReader.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return log;
    }
```

Is there a way to make my code read from the file in max 5 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried `File.ReadAllText` method?

Comment: Yeah, that one only works when the file is not used by another process

Answer (score 0):

I got it. When I use stream.ReadToEnd() it reads everything in about 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned file is big, so better to use `StringBuilder` over `string`, you can use `using` also so no need to call `close()` explicitly.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string path = "some path";
using (FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader logFileReader = new StreamReader(logFileStream))
    {
        while (!logFileReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            sb.Append(logFileReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }

}

string log = sb.ToString();
```